# RewriteRule not working correctly

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

So I have been trying to get the `RewriteRule` to work for awhile now but it won't start working as it keeps throwing a `404 error` at me yet when I use WordPress it works fine. Here is the `.htaccess` file (Note: This is on a cPanel Server aka Shared Hosting)

```
RewriteEngine on
Options -Multiviews
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^request/([A-Z,a-z]+)[/]?$ req.php?user=$1 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://nightcore.nightmusic.gdn/$1 [L,R=301,NC]
```

Comment: what's the error? any error log?

Comment: nope not any error logs at all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since its a shared server , the better deal is it contact the share hosting support provider and give them all the details of the issue and they will be able to fix the issue for you.